# how to select single input from multiple output in Simulink?

Tags: simulation, matlab, simulink, matlab-guide

Could any one tell me how can i use a Multiport switch in the following example. i can use alternatively MATLAB funtion block with M script but its slow. 2 days before i try to use a sum block as shown in **figure2** and i thought i am genius and and i was succed. But Today Morning i am getting a 'Ghombaro Result'(Unexpeted Result)' i.e  during simulation mode when i am changing my input level the pervious output is remain same and its adding up i thought it will replace it with ZERO ... :( ..... is there any way to do it by using another block or with any idea...
[image]

[image].

Thank you...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Merge](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/merge.html?refresh=true) block, to merge all input from your *'If Action Subsystems'*, set Initial Output as `0`.
Connect the output of merge block to the 'Display' block

[image]

Comment: Hi POW Could You Please tell me how can i **Disable LOOK UNDER MASK **Option by using **set_param** funtion. I think it coud be new question but Could You Please.............

Comment: @user2851655 Ummm.. probably a new post. Two benefits a) Help other usres b) If I'm not able to answer others can help